# jQuery form plugin and PHP file uploads tutorial questions

Tags: javascript, php, xml, forms

I found nice [tutorial](http://www.web-development-blog.com/archives/jquery-form-plugin-and-php-file-uploads/) about jquery php file upload but my knowledge  is`t that well because i dont know where put these samples of code... and what is xml file ?

i have 2 files :

1-named kontakt.php with body of the simple contact form body

`<form action="contact.php" method="post" id="my-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

2-file named contact.php to php scripts.

Im trying to do some basic operations with files with no effect.
Can u write me some directions about these parts of the code because i dont recognize them wery well

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Alright, let's do this:

1. **XML** stands for Extensible Markup Language. It is a markup language, similar to HTML to store general data.
2. You put those two files on the root (main) directory on a webserver.
3. The code you posted up top isn't the complete contact form HTML. Use the *whole* code from the tutorial.

   `<div id="container">
       <form action="process.php" method="post" id="my-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
           <p>E-mail<br />
           <input type="text" name="email" id="email" /></p>
           <p>File<br />
           <input type="file" name="upload" id="upload" /></p>
           <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
       </form>
   </div>
   <div id="output"></div>`
4. Don't name your files similarly, or you won't know which one is which 2 weeks from now. For example, use *index.html* for the form page and *upload.php* for the processing page.
5. Otherwise, just follow the directions of the tutorial.

You might also want to check out this tutorial, I think it is a bit more clear:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp